# How do you access the different dimensions in a table in R ( table() function)?

Tags: r, contingency

I created a multidimensional contingency table in R using the `table()` function.

Here's the code I used to create my table:

```
    tab <- table(nba$zoneBasic, nba$close_def_dist, nba$touch_time,nba$period, nba$off_dribble, 
    dnn=c('Zone','Closest Defender Distance','Touch Time','Quarter','Off Dribble'))

    tab
```

And here is a screenshot of a portion of the output:

[image]

How do I access the different dimensions as shown in the output and convert them into separate tables? I've tried indexing (`tab[1]`) as a simple way to access the dimensions, but that doesn't work since `table()` isn't actually creating separate tables as it appears in the output.

Comment: With 3d tables you need 3 indices, `tab[1,,]` or `tab[,1,]` or `tab[,,1]` or `tab[1,1,]` or...

Answer (score 0):

It is a multi-dimensional array.  An easier option is to convert to long format to `data.frame`

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(tab)
```

---

Or if we want a single table use `ftable`

```
ftable(nba[c("zoneBasic", "close_def_dist",
   "touch_time" , "period", "off_dribble")]
```